# Class library has no Program.cs - where to configure DI?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, .net-6.0

I started a new class library project and I want to use Dependency Injection for services and `DbContext`, etc.

However there is no `Program.cs` file.

Where should I configure the DI interfaces and classes? Do I need to add an empty `Program.cs`?

Comment: The application which uses your library will have to call into it at some point, and ask it to set up its DI. How exactly you go about this really depends on how your library will be used, whether you want the application to be able to add types / get types from the DI container, etc

Answer (score 5, accepted):

for example, if you have a class library as a business access layer. you can add a class in the root with the name **DependencyInjection** as the following

```
public static class DependencyInjection
    {
        public static void AddApplication(this IServiceCollection service)
        {
            service.AddScoped<IOrgSettingsService, OrgSettingsService>();
            service.AddScoped<IIdentity, IdentityService>();
            service.AddScoped<ILdapAuthenticationService, LdapAuthenticationService>();
            service.AddScoped<IOrgAuthenticationService, OrgAuthenticationService>();
            service.AddScoped<IVacanciesService, VacancyService>();
            
            // assemblers
            service.AddScoped<IVacancyAssembler, VacancyAssembler>();

        }
    }
```

and register it in startup class as the following

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
         // ...
          services.AddApplication();
        }
```

Comment: Fyi: You have to add `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions` as a nuget dependency in your class library

Comment: but a class library project does not have a startup?

Answer (score 1):

dependency injection used for whole application.Main application injects services to all assemblies. for example, dbcontext inject from main application to your assembly.You should not define dependency instance for each assembly separately and locally